# Manually connecting two Docker containers: SQL Server and Jupyter Lab - Error: ('IM004')

Tags: sql-server, docker, odbc, jupyter-lab

I'm currently working as a data analyst for a healthcare company, the DataLake infrastructure is in SQL Server and I'm currently trying to analyze the current state of all the databases in a Jupyter Lab Notebook for a structured writing reasons.

I have also been using Docker Containers since few months ago because I find them the better tools in order to get a good computing performance while working in isolated environments for security reasons. That's why I don't have that much of experience using docker.

I want to maintain a hands-on programming approach.

I've been trying to create the connection via Docker Network and it seems to be working nicely, but when it comes to connecting to the database using "pyodbc", "SQLAlchemy" and "SQL Magic", it always shows this error message:

> Error: ('IM004', "[IM004] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

I've established the following manual connection process:

**Docker Configuration Stage**

- A shell is opened
- Creating a bridge between containers:

  - SQL Server - Jupyter:

Create a container network:

```
docker network create **networkname**
```

Create and connect the containers to the network:

```
docker run --rm -t -d --name=**jupytercontainername** -p 8888:8888 --mount src="$(pwd)",target=/"Users",type=bind --network **networkname** **jupyterimagename**
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_PID=Developer" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=**sqlpassword**" -e "MSSQL_TCP_PORT=1433" -p 1433:1433 -d --name **sqlcontainername** --network **networkname** sqlserver:2022-latest
```

Note that these commands are the same as those used for creating isolated containers, with the addition of connecting them to the created network.

Deploy the container and enter it:

```
docker exec -ti **jupytercontainername** bash
```

Install the required ODBC driver:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev odbcinst
```

Verify the installation of the driver:

```
find / -name libodbc.so.2
find / -name odbcinst.ini
```

Exit the container to restart it and apply the changes:

```
exit
docker restart **jupytercontainername**
docker exec -ti **jupytercontainername** bash
```

Adjust the PATH for libodbc.so.2:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Edit odbcinst.ini for the ODBC driver for SQL Server:

```
apt-get install nano
nano /etc/odbcinst.ini
```

Enter the following content:

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description = Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver      = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.2
```

Save and exit nano:

```
    (Ctrl + O) Guardar
    (Ctrl + X) Salir
```

Confirm the configuration of `odbcinst.ini`:

```
odbcinst -q -d -n "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
```

It should display the same content as entered using the nano text editor, as described in the previous step.

Register odbcinst.ini in the system:

```
odbcinst -i -d -f /etc/odbcinst.ini
```

Exit the container to restart it and apply the changes:

```
exit
docker restart **jupytercontainername**
docker exec -ti **jupytercontainername** bash
```

Open Jupyter Lab:

```
jupyter lab --ip='0.0.0.0' --port=8888 --no-browser --allow-root
```

**Jupyter Connection Stage**

- Jupyter is opened in the browser
- Libraries are installed:

```
!pip install --upgrade pip
!pip install pyodbc  # Controlador ODBC para SQL Server
!pip install sqlalchemy # Librería ORM para conectarse a bases de datos desde Python
!pip install ipython-sql  # SQL Magic
!pip install pandas # Para el análisis de las BD's
```

Libraries are imported:

```
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd
```

SQL Magic extension is called:

```
%load_ext sql
```

pyodbc connection is created:

```
hostname = '**servername**'
port = 1433
database = '**databasename**'
username = '**usiernamename**'
password = '**passwordname**'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+hostname+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

Here's where the error appears:

> Error
> Traceback (most recent call last)
> Cell In[4], line 9
> 5 username = '**usiernamename**'
> 6 password = '**passwordname**'
> ----> 9 cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+hostname+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
> 10 cursor = cnxn.cursor()
>
> Error: ('IM004', "[IM004] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

SQL Magic connection is created:

```
    hostname = '**servername**'
    port = 1433
    database = '**databasename**'
    username = '**usiernamename**'
    password = '**passwordname**'

    connection_string = f'mssql+pyodbc://{username}:{password}@{hostname}/{database}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'

    Charging the SQL Magic connection
    %sql $connection_string
```

The same error appears:

```
        sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('IM004', "[IM004] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
        (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/dbapi)
    
        Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
                       postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
                       or an existing connection: dict_keys([])
```

After several days of investigation, I've come to the conclusion that it seems to be either an ODBC configuration issue or an ODBC PATH configuration issue, because I tried the pyodbc connection in the general host and it worked perfectly.

I'd be very pleased if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Where exactly are you installing the Microsoft-supplied ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server? Seems like you're hacking the `/etc/odbcinst.ini` file to have `Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.2` whereas if ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server had been installed normally this line would read something like `Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.10.so.5.1`.

Comment: I would suggest confirming which Linux distribution and version is used in your Jupyter image with `cat /etc/os-release` and then following the distro-specific instructions to [Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (Linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?tabs=alpine18-install%2Calpine17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline#17)

Comment: So, it looks like it has somenthing to do with the:
`docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_PID=Developer" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=**sqlpassword**" -e "MSSQL_TCP_PORT=1433" -p 1433:1433 -d --name **sqlcontainername** --network **networkname** sqlserver:2022-latest`

Since **I didn't put the database credentials on the SQL docker run chain**, thus, i'd like to know if it's possible to stablish a DB connection from the docker container itself. It would be like **creating a connection instance in the docker container**.